# How to parse a number having zeros after "+" sign in javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, phone-number, libphonenumber

I have numbers saved in the given formats:

eg:

```
+060169034675
+003478596956
...
+000057465744
```

The ***libphonenumber-js*** library cannot parse this number, gives an error.

Now I want to delete the zeros after '+' sign, then it will be easy to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must try parseInt function which will return you number.

```js
console.log(parseInt("+0060169034675"));
 console.log("+"+parseInt("+0060169034675"));
```

Comment: thank you, it is helpful, but why the library gives an error , it should say something like invalid or  wrong etc. There must be a way to parse it

Comment: It seems to be appear due to '+' icon , js read it as concatenation , as i got